# I want to use the id of the selected button but how can i take the id from it? this.id doesnt work

Tags: javascript, rest

I want to use the id of the selected button for a delete.
But i dont know how i can take/get the id from it.
I tried this.id but that doesnt work.

This is where i create the button:

```
var deleteEmployer= document.createElement("td");

var deleteEmployerButton= document.createElement("input");
deleteEmployerButton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
deleteEmployerButton.setAttribute("value", "delete");               
deleteEmployerButton.setAttribute("id", employer.employer_id);
deleteEmployer.appendChild(deleteEmployerButton);

deleteEmployer.addEventListener("click", deleteEmployFunc);
row.appendChild(deleteEmployer);

document.querySelector("#Employer").appendChild(row);
```

This is the `deleteEmployFunc`:

```
function deleteEmployFunc() {
    var id = this.id;

    console.log(id);

    fetch("restservices/employer/" + id, { method: 'DELETE' })
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.ok) {
                window.location.reload();
            } else if (response.status == 404) {
                console.log("Employer not found")
            } else {
                console.log("Can't delete employer")
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: You're adding event listener to the table cell, not the button. The table cell doesn't have ID...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the event handler to `deleteEmployer` not `deleteEmployerButton`

Here's a minimal example that should work:

```js
var deleteEmployerButton = document.createElement("input");
deleteEmployerButton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
deleteEmployerButton.setAttribute("value", "delete");    
deleteEmployerButton.setAttribute("id", "randomID");

deleteEmployerButton.addEventListener("click", deleteEmployFunc);
    
document.querySelector("#Employer").appendChild(deleteEmployerButton);



//This is the "deleteEmployFunc" :

function deleteEmployFunc() {

  var id = this.id;

  console.log(id);

  fetch("restservices/employer/" + id, {method: 'DELETE'} )
      .then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
          window.location.reload();   
        } else if (response.status == 404) {
           console.log("Employer not found")
        } else {
          console.log("Can't delete employer") 
        }            
      });
}
```

```html
<div id="Employer"></div>
```

When you click the button, you should see the `randomID` be outputted.

Answer (score 0):

`this` does not refer to your button. In order to get the `id` you can set a property on your `deleteEmployFunc` while appending that references the button and can be used within the function itself.

```js
var employer = { employer_id: 1234 };
var deleteEmployer= document.createElement("td");

var deleteEmployerButton= document.createElement("input");

function deleteEmployFunc() {
console.log(deleteEmployFunc.deleteButton.id);
}

deleteEmployerButton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
deleteEmployerButton.setAttribute("value", "delete");               
deleteEmployerButton.setAttribute("id", employer.employer_id);

deleteEmployFunc.deleteButton = deleteEmployer.appendChild(deleteEmployerButton);

deleteEmployer.addEventListener("click", deleteEmployFunc);

document.querySelector("#Employer").appendChild(deleteEmployer);
```

```html
<div id="Employer"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in other answers, you `addEventListener` to wrong object. There are more issues with the code. Look at them.

```js
var employer = {
  employer_id: 111
};

//var deleteEmployer= document.createElement("td"); //table and table row objects have their own DOM functions
var row = document.querySelector('#Employer') //a table
  .insertRow(-1); //add as last row
var deleteEmployer = row.insertCell(-1); //add to the end of Cells collection of the row

var deleteEmployerButton = document.createElement("input"); //OK
// redundant. type is a standard attribute
//deleteEmployerButton.setAttribute("type", "submit");
deleteEmployerButton.type = 'button'; //submit submits the form

deleteEmployerButton.value = "delete";
//no need as you see below
//deleteEmployerButton.setAttribute("id", employer.employer_id);
deleteEmployer.appendChild(deleteEmployerButton); //OK

deleteEmployerButton.addEventListener("click", deleteEmployFunc(employer.employer_id)); // see the trick below
//row.appendChild(deleteEmployer); // already done

//document.querySelector("#Employer").appendChild(row); // table.insertRow(-1) is better

//This is the deleteEmployFunc:

function deleteEmployFunc(id) {
  return function() {

    console.log(id);
    /* commented for test / demo purpose
        fetch("restservices/employer/" + id, {
            method: 'DELETE'
          })
          .then(function(response) {
            if (response.ok) {
              window.location.reload();
            } else if (response.status == 404) {
              console.log("Employer not found")
            } else {
              console.log("Can't delete employer")
            }
          });
          */
  };
}
```

```html
<table id="Employer"></table>
```